# Evaluate $ 2\pi \int_0^1 \ln(x^2+2)\sqrt{1+\frac{4x^2}{(x^2+2)^2}}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

I've been trying to solve this this problem for so long but haven't had much luck, can someone please help me out?

The original question was:

Find the area of the part of the surface $z = \ln(x^2+y^2+2)$ that lies above the disk $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ correct to four decimal places by expressing the area in terms of a single integral.

I set up the integral as:

$$
2\pi \int_0^1 \ln(x^2+2)\sqrt{1+\frac{4x^2}{(x^2+2)^2}}\,dx.
$$

edit 1: Sorry for being unclear, I need a numerical value at the end, I've tried solving it by parts but it hasn't gotten me anywhere. I could just put it into a calculator and get an answer but I'm more curious about how to actually set it up and the steps to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Mathematica doesn't return anything; are you sure you're supposed to give an exact value, or are you just supposed to set up the integral?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please share what you have tried, where you are stuck, etc. What is the source of the problem? If you don't add these kind of details, I fear that this question will soon be closed, since it still does not match the quality standards of MSE...

Comment: Did you evaluate a numerical result ?

Comment: I'm having trouble posting a photo of my work...

Comment: Pictures are discouraged unless absolutely necessary. You are encouraged to typeset your query, as I have.

Comment: my bad, I edited the post!

Comment: I don't get the solid of revolution tag. To find the area of the surface over the disk $D:x^2+y^2\le 1$ you should solve $$\iint\limits_D {\sqrt {z_x ^2  + z_y ^2  + 1} \,dA}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solid of revolution. The proble asks the area of the surface $z\log \left(x^2+y^2+2\right)$ inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

$z=\log \left(x^2+y^2+2\right)$ and $D:x^2+y^2\le 1$

$$S=\iint\limits_{D} \sqrt{z_x^2+z_y^2+1}\,dA$$

$$z_x=\frac{2 x}{x^2+y^2+2};\;z_y=\frac{2 y}{x^2+y^2+2}$$

$$S=\iint\limits_{D} \sqrt{z_x^2+z_y^2+1}\,dA$$

$$S=\iint\limits_{D}\sqrt{\frac{4 x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2+2\right)^2}+\frac{4 y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2+2\right)^2}+1}\,dA$$
$$S=\iint\limits_{D}\sqrt{1+\frac{4 \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2+2\right)^2}}\,dA$$
Changing to polar coordinates
$x=r\cos t;\;y=r\sin t$ and $Jacobian = r$ we get
$$S=\int _0^1\int _0^{2 \pi } r \sqrt{\frac{4 r^2}{\left(r^2+2\right)^2}+1}\,dtdr$$
$$S=\int _0^1\int _0^{2 \pi }\frac{r }{r^2+2}\sqrt{r^4+8 r^2+4}\,dtdr$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(2 \sqrt{13}-4+\log \left(\frac{1}{162} \left(95 \sqrt{13}+343\right)\right)-4 \sqrt{2} \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)+4 \sqrt{2} \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{26}\right)\right)\approx 3.5618$$